# How To Convert Flat List To 2-Dimentional Cross Table

Tags: r, linux

Is there a way to convert a flat list to a 2-dimensional table? The flat list has three columns (x value, y value and score). It lists every x-y pair in a long list. I would like to make a x-y table with the score in the proper x-y cell. This can be done in Excel with Kutools in Windows, but I do not have Windows. Is there a way to do this with R or Linux?
Input list:

```
a a 1
a b 2
a c 3
b b 1
b c 2
c c 1
```

desired output table:

```
    a b c
a   1 2 3
b     1 2
c       1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just use `xtabs` `xtabs(v3~v1 + v2, df1)` assuming the columns are 'v1', 'v2', and 'v3'